# Как взять полностью всю строку после команды в discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Проблема такая: есть команда в дискорде, и после команды вся остальная строка записывается в переменную, код:

```
bot.command()
async def command(ctx, message : str):
```

Но если, например, ввести в чат !command example and example, то в переменную message пойдет только одно слово, то есть 'example', как сделать так, чтобы после после команды абсолютно вся оставшаяся часть строки записывалась в переменную 'message'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать переменную keyword-only аргументом (kwarg): https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments

```
@bot.command()
async def command(ctx, *, message:str):
    ...
```